# How to restrict users from calling specific methods

Tags: ruby

I have a class that contains a bunch of methods, I have written unit tests for each method. The main method in the class is the `encrypt` method, which takes a message and encrypts it. I have also written like 5 other methods that are used by this encrypt method, but I don't want the user to be able to call these methods, I just want to use them inside the encrypt method to get the job done, but I don't want the user to do like @obj.some_method_that_is_not_encrypt, I want to make only the `encrypt` method invokable, I know I can make these methods private, but then my unit tests will fail. How do I go about dealing with this ?

Comment: see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267237/whats-the-best-way-to-unit-test-protected-private-methods-in-ruby   you can use send to get around the private.

Comment: @Doon but isn't this smelly?

Comment: Smell determination is left as an exercise for the reader :)  it opens up a whole new can of worms.  But the fact that your (or your classes) users can do this and bypass private means private should be treated as a suggestion  anyways.  But alas I don't have a good answer for it.. I normally test the public interfaces / behavior of the class as opposed to each function, for right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit tests can use [`Object#send(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-send) to invoke private methods:

```
class Foo
private
  def bar
    "ok"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar # => NoMethodError: private method `bar' called...
f.send(:bar) # => "ok"
```

So your "encrypt" method could be the only public one but it can still use private methods which are not exposed to *polite* users of your library (they can, of course, use `send` also if they want).

Note also that a peculiar aspect of "private" methods is that they cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, even in the same class.  So you could not call `self.my_private_method`, instead you must simply call `my_private_method`.  For example:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    self.bar # => NoMethodError: private method `bar' called...
    bar # => "ok"
  end
private
  def bar; "ok"; end
end
```