# The meaning of calling 'send' with ':public' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can do ...

```
Object.send(:public, *Object.private_instance_methods)
```

... as seen in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269452/616987). This redefines each of the private instance methods of `Object`, making them public. My question is: how does this work? `send` is supposed to work with the name of a method, but there do not seem to be methods named `public`, `private`, or `protected` defined on `Object` (or at least my search-fu has not found them).

```
> Object.respond_to?(:public)
=> false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a method called `public`, but it is defined on [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-public). This is ok because `Object` is an instance of `Class` and the superclass of `Class` is `Module`: apart from the slight circularity in the ruby class hierarchy bootstrapping this is just normal ruby inheritance.

Your `respond_to?` check returns false because by default `respond_to?` does not check protected or private methods (prior to ruby 2.0 it checked protected methods). You can request that all methods be searched by doing

```
Object.respond_to?(:public, true)
```

which does return true.

Comment: Interesting! Also, after tinkering around further, I see that making the private methods of Object public does not make the mixed in methods from Module public.